# Notifications for comments under answers

Tags: support, comments, notifications

Alice posts a question.  Bob posts an answer.  I want to comment on Bob's answer, and I want both Alice and Bob to be notified of the comment.  Therefore I type something like "@Alice:  As @Bob said....".

I then get a pop-up notice that says I can have only one @-sign per comment.   Fine.  The same notice tells me that the "owner of the post" will be notified automatically, and therefore I should allocate my @-sign to the non-owner.  However, I have no idea whether Alice or Bob counts as the "owner of the post".  Is "the post" the question or is it the answer?

**Question 1:**  In this situation, who is the relevant "owner of the post"?

**Question 2:**  Can the pop-up text be modified so that other users won't have to ask this question in the future?

Answer (score 3):

If the post is an answer, the post owner is the author of the answer. In this case, that's Bob. Ideally, you could say something like "*@Alice and Bob, (whatever)*". If you're commenting under a question, the post owner is the author of the question, and people who've written answers cannot be tagged with `@` symbols unless they have left comments under the question (needless to say, they definitely won't be pinged automatically).

I don't think we need a modification in the message because there's an [faq](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) on [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com) which should be linked in the page the pop-up takes you to: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019) It's probably not feasible to add a direct link to the comment `@` replies section because we don't have enough space for that level of detail.

Comment: It might be worth rewording this to say that the post owner is the _author of the post you're commenting on_. That way, people who are similarly confused but were trying to comment on a question instead can read this and come away with something that helps them as well.

Comment: Also, is the FAQ post actually linked in the popup? It doesn't look like it is to me. (I tried it on this post)

Comment: @DavidZ It's linked indirectly, though I think what I wrote states otherwise. The popup has a page titled 'how do comments work', and there's a link from there to the MSE post about @ replies. I'll make an edit. It's tricky to say "_the post owner is the author of the post you're commenting on_" because some new users may consider the combination of the question and the answer to be a single post. That being said, there's no harm in adding a bit more detail to make this less ambiguous for future users; I'll do that in a moment.

Comment: @DavidZ :  I actually think that's an entirely unhelpful rewording.  If I'm commenting on Bob's answer to Alice's question, and if I'm told that the post owner is *the author of the post I'm commenting on*, I have no idea whether "the post I'm commenting on" refers to Alice's question or to Bob's answer.  A large part of the problem in the first place is that the phrase "the post" is ambiguous.  (And yes, I do now see the logic of why "the post I'm commenting on" refers to the answer, but for me, at least, it took a little while for that to click.)

Comment: @WillO It's straightforward enough to use "question or answer" instead of "post" if that helps. Anyway, I guess I don't see it being that confusing that when you type in the comment box under an answer, you are commenting on that answer. I mean, of course _some_ people will not get that, but I'm a little skeptical that it's a high fraction of users, even of relatively new users. I wonder if there's a good way to find out? Of course, ultimately the goal is to come up with clearer wording, which will be great if possible; I personally don't have any ideas.

Comment: @WillO If that is in fact unclear wording (i.e. if the population of users that find it confusing is nontrivial), then this meta is the wrong venue for it - that needs to be dealt with at the SE-wide level at [meta.se].